# Handling a nested array in Flask request

Tags: python, ajax, flask, jsonp

I built a webserver in Flask and I'm passing in the request using jsonp. One of the things I pass in is an nested array and when I retrieve the data in Flask, the array is completely messed up.
Here's my code

**index.html**

```
var array = [[2,1],[2,2],[2,3]]
function getNext() {
    var data = {
        'M': 5,
        'N': 5,
        'array' : array
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/getNewGeneration',
        jsonp: 'callback',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

**server.py**

```
@app.route('/getNewGeneration')
def getNext():
    M = request.args.get('M')
    N = request.args.get('N')
    liveCells = request.args.get('liveCells')
    ...
```

When I print out `request.args` I get `ImmutableMultiDict([('callback', u'jQuery17101683842277548142_1412736365518'), ('array[2][]', u'2'), ('array[2][]', u'3'), ('array[1][]', u'2'), ('array[1][]', u'2'), ('N', u'5'), ('M', u'5'), ('_', u'1412736417145'), ('array[0][]', u'2'), ('array[0][]', u'1')])`

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: is `request.json` also that messed up?

Comment: request.json returned None

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two problems with your code. First, you don't pass a key named `'liveCells'`. You pass one named `'array'`. You need to update this either in your JavaScript or on the Flask side. Assuming you want the former, your JavaScript should look like

```
var array = [[2,1],[2,2],[2,3]]
function getNext() {
    var data = {
        'M': 5,
        'N': 5,
        'liveCells' : array
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/getNewGeneration',
        jsonp: 'callback',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

Second, you can't use the `get` method to retrieve multivalve keys. `ImmutableMultiDict`s, such as `request.args`, provide a method called `getlist` that will return a list of items for the given key rather than a single value. Update your code to

```
liveCells = request.args.getlist('liveCells')
```

More information can be found in the [`werkzeug` documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist).

Comment: This is the only answer I've found on SO that mentions there is a `getList` function, so thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this and i think it will work for you.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'getNewGeneration',
    success: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

And try to print `request.json` then.